# How to design two themes switching on selection?

Tags: ios, iphone, uistoryboard, ios-autolayout, ui-design

I am making a timer application inside View Controller on Main Content View i am adding all the subview like Cycles, Seconds , Sets, Start Button etc..

...according to my new requirement i need to make another Content view with different layout (new Theme).

But while designing i face difficulty in setting constraints..as it sets it to the view behind it many times...is there any other correct method to design so that i can design my content view separately and import while switching.I know only this approach..

Comment: Make separate custom view (inherits UIView) for each theme and just add it as subview on your ViewController's View as per need.

Comment: That is good..but how about doing using storyboard...

Comment: I think you can do this by adding 2 views in the same viewceontroller in storyboard, each with different design and referencing outlets for both views. You can hide and unhide as per need.